# SMS listener, best way?

Tags: android

I need to make application that will catch EVERY SINGLE SMS that phone receives, and forward that SMS to email adress. So, i'm wondering how to perform that - should I make that as service or as application? User should open the application only once, and forget that it's running on his phone.
I really don't know how to manage this because I'm not experienced Java programmer,

If i make that as Service I assume that it would need to be running always, so it could 'listen' for incoming SMS's. (it doesn't help if it turns on periodically because than it's possible to miss some messages while being turned off). And i'm not sure if that's even possible?

If i make that as Application, could I achieve that effect through this way: 
when default SMS application receives message, phone also notifies my app and so wake it up, and than my app cathes sms and do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a BroadcastReciever to get SMS and then to send as email you might have to write a Service. You can check [here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that's just how i've done it! But the problem is that when i turn the application on and leave the phone, after 30-40 minutes i see that phone killed the app and stoped it. So i need to do something in order to keep application always running, that's the main problem :(

Comment: broadcast Receivers are never killed, when you have installed the app, they are registered and they will always be called when the intent filter is matched

Comment: I hadn't realised that so far, you've just helped me in solving that problem! Thank you very much, now my application keeps running even after phone reboot! But unfortunately another problem came up - I'm using BroadcastReciever, as you [advised](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2008/12/android-api-sms-handling/) me also,and i used [this](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android) for sending that SMS to email, using GMAIL client. I've put `permission.INTERNET` in AndroidManifest.xml but app just breaks down!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot process internet related tasks on the actual UI thread - it's bad practice anyway. You need to process any internet related tasks through the use of use AsyncTask to handle this. Check out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html